# Regex for a promo code that has the following rules

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex that have the following:

Rules to be applied:

- exactly 14 characters
- only letters (latin characters) and numbers
- at least 3 letters

Regex still confuses me so I am struggling to get the correct output. I want to use it with swift and swiftui in an app I am making

(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){3,}([0-9]){0,}){14,14}$

I tried this. But I know it is not the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){3})[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}$
```

*Details*

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(?:[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){3})` - at least three repeations of a letter after any zero or more digits sequence required
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{14}` - fourteen letters/digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/09dA6q/1).

Comment: It worked! One question, what does the (?=?: mean in the regex?

Comment: @kikuchan `(?=...)` is a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and the `(?:....)` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/3832970).

Answer (score 3):

I would use a positive lookahead for the length requirement:

```
^(?=.{14}$)(?:[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]){3}[A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

This pattern says to match:

- `^` from the start of the input
- `(?=.{14}$)` assert exact length of 14
- `(?:`

  - `[A-Za-z0-9]*[A-Za-z]` zero or more alphanumeric followed by one alpha
- `)`
- `[A-Za-z0-9]*` any alphanumeric zero or more times
- `$` end of the input